# Angularjs - multiplas abas no mesmo navegador

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Estou utilizando angularJS em minha aplicação Node. Quando tento abrir uma outra Aba também com minha aplicação no mesmo navegador ( ou abrir outra instância do mesmo navegador ) recebo esse erro:

```
s:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0(anonymous function) @ utils.js:14
angular.js:13236 SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at Object.parse (native)
at new MyController (http://meuProjeto/my.controller.js:8:28)
at Object.invoke (http://meuProjeto/js/libs/angular-1.5.0/angular.js:4604:19)
at extend.instance (http://meuProjeto/js/libs/angular-1.5.0/angular.js:9855:34)
at nodeLinkFn (http://meuProjeto/js/libs/angular-1.5.0/angular.js:8927:34)
at compositeLinkFn (http://meuProjeto/js/libs/angular-1.5.0/angular.js:8226:13)
at publicLinkFn (http://meuProjeto/js/libs/angular-1.5.0/angular.js:8106:30)
at http://meuProjeto/js/libs/angular-1.5.0/angular.js:1696:27
at Scope.$eval (http://meuProjeto/js/libs/angular-1.5.0/angular.js:16820:28)
at Scope.$apply (http://meuProjeto/js/libs/angular-1.5.0/angular.js:16920:25)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13236
```

no meu script `utils.js` na linha 14 tem o seguinte comando:

```
var param = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.param);
```

Sei que é bem genérico o que postei, porém sou novato em desenvolvimento WEB e estou postando isto torcendo para que alguém tenha passado pelo mesmo problema (ou por algo parecido) e possa me guiar! Não faço ideia de onde começar a procurar uma solução, postei por isso também.

Caso seja necessário posso adicionar alguma informação que seja relevante e eu não tenha colocado aqui.

Desde já, grato!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sessionStorage` pertence exclusivamente à sessão *do browser*, que é vinculada à página.

Caso deseje compartilhar conteúdo entre duas ou mais tab/janelas, utilize `localStorage`.

Exemplo de implementação:

```
app.factory('userService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var service = {
        model: {
            name: '',
            email: ''
        },

        SaveState: function () {
            sessionStorage.userService = angular.toJson(service.model);
        },

        RestoreState: function () {
            service.model = angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.userService);
        }
    }

    $rootScope.$on("savestate", service.SaveState);
    $rootScope.$on("restorestate", service.RestoreState);

    return service;
}]);
```

(fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247130/how-to-store-the-data-to-local-storage)

Abaixo uma lista de serviços que podem lhe ajudar:

- https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage
- http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e pela explicação OnoSendai . Irei testar a sua resposta e assim que terminar irei marcá-la como correta!

Comment: Nos links que você forneceu, encontrei um deles explicando o uso do sessionStorage e do localStorage. Troquei como você disse o sessionStorage pelo localStorage e aparentemente está tudo ok! Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha funcionado. Sinta-se à vontade para perguntar se possuíres outras dúvidas!